# PackageManager$NameNotFoundException for rxAndroidBle

Tags: android, rx-android, rxandroidble, jitpack

For version 1.12.1, I am getting a runtime exception after upgrading to this version from 1.10.5

```
2021-07-16 15:30:16.588 22665-22665/co.(appname).staging E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: co.(appname).staging:svc, PID: 22665
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/jakewharton/rxrelay2/BehaviorRelay;
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.DeviceModule.provideConnectionStateRelay(DeviceModule.java:57)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.DeviceModule_ProvideConnectionStateRelayFactory.get(DeviceModule_ProvideConnectionStateRelayFactory.java:17)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.DeviceModule_ProvideConnectionStateRelayFactory.get(DeviceModule_ProvideConnectionStateRelayFactory.java:9)
        at bleshadow.dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.RxBleDeviceImpl_Factory.get(RxBleDeviceImpl_Factory.java:31)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.RxBleDeviceImpl_Factory.get(RxBleDeviceImpl_Factory.java:11)
        at bleshadow.dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.DaggerClientComponent$DeviceComponentImpl.provideDevice(DaggerClientComponent.java:509)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.RxBleDeviceProvider.getBleDevice(RxBleDeviceProvider.java:43)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.scan.InternalToExternalScanResultConverter.apply(InternalToExternalScanResultConverter.java:26)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.scan.InternalToExternalScanResultConverter.apply(InternalToExternalScanResultConverter.java:13)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap$MapObserver.onNext(ObservableMap.java:57)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableUnsubscribeOn$UnsubscribeObserver.onNext(ObservableUnsubscribeOn.java:60)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onNext(ObservableCreate.java:66)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.serialization.FIFORunnableEntry$1$1.onNext(FIFORunnableEntry.java:68)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableUnsubscribeOn$UnsubscribeObserver.onNext(ObservableUnsubscribeOn.java:60)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onNext(ObservableCreate.java:66)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.operations.ScanOperationApi21$1.onScanResult(ScanOperationApi21.java:83)
        at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper$1.run(BluetoothLeScanner.java:492)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.jakewharton.rxrelay2.BehaviorRelay" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~azBMNu86abFT1X-EHOpB2A==/co.(appname).staging-eYQb5VbY1nmgyq2oa0oeWA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~azBMNu86abFT1X-EHOpB2A==/co.(appname).staging-eYQb5VbY1nmgyq2oa0oeWA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~azBMNu86abFT1X-EHOpB2A==/co.(appname).staging-eYQb5VbY1nmgyq2oa0oeWA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.DeviceModule.provideConnectionStateRelay(DeviceModule.java:57) 
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.DeviceModule_ProvideConnectionStateRelayFactory.get(DeviceModule_ProvideConnectionStateRelayFactory.java:17) 
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.DeviceModule_ProvideConnectionStateRelayFactory.get(DeviceModule_ProvideConnectionStateRelayFactory.java:9) 
        at bleshadow.dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47) 
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.RxBleDeviceImpl_Factory.get(RxBleDeviceImpl_Factory.java:31) 
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.RxBleDeviceImpl_Factory.get(RxBleDeviceImpl_Factory.java:11) 
        at bleshadow.dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47) 
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.DaggerClientComponent$DeviceComponentImpl.provideDevice(DaggerClientComponent.java:509) 
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.RxBleDeviceProvider.getBleDevice(RxBleDeviceProvider.java:43) 
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.scan.InternalToExternalScanResultConverter.apply(InternalToExternalScanResultConverter.java:26) 
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.scan.InternalToExternalScanResultConverter.apply(InternalToExternalScanResultConverter.java:13) 
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap$MapObserver.onNext(ObservableMap.java:57) 
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableUnsubscribeOn$UnsubscribeObserver.onNext(ObservableUnsubscribeOn.java:60) 
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onNext(ObservableCreate.java:66) 
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.serialization.FIFORunnableEntry$1$1.onNext(FIFORunnableEntry.java:68) 
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableUnsubscribeOn$UnsubscribeObserver.onNext(ObservableUnsubscribeOn.java:60) 
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onNext(ObservableCreate.java:66) 
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.operations.ScanOperationApi21$1.onScanResult(ScanOperationApi21.java:83) 
        at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper$1.run(BluetoothLeScanner.java:492) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

The catch? I have forked the repo, made a couple very small changes (like small changes to timeouts for example), and created a build with Jitpack. I checked their Jitpack build log (https://jitpack.io/com/github/polidea/RxAndroidBle/release-1.12.1-rxjava2/build.log) against my own, and they are almost identical. I see the missing errors, I have the exact same ones. The difference is that if I use the official polidea rxAndroidBle gradle thing (which I believe is pulled from Jitpack), I do not get the same runtime issue.

I have been looking for hours and feel like I am at a dead-end. I wanted to create an issue against the repo, but I am not confident that it is their issue. Something specific with what I have done with the build, but I do not know where the difference could be.

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem when using Jitpack to build the RxCentralBle library.

Did you find how to solve this or it is not possible to use Jitpack right now with this library?

Comment: I've opened an issue in the library. I leave it here for traceability https://github.com/uber/RxCentralBle/issues/50

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by adding again the missing libraries that are not resolved when publishing a version with JitPack.

```
android: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0',
java   : 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2',
relay  : 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.1.0'
```